# zsh: command not found: denon - Even after installing denon

Tags: macos, terminal, deno

I install denon on my mac and then tried to run this cmd: `denon --init`

I get this message `zsh: command not found: denon`

Even when I try to check for the version using `denon --version`, it throws the same message.

Answer (score 15):

After some googling and trial and error I found the solution to the above problem.

Looks like denon got installed at a different path. So we need to provide the correct path.

Run the below cmd in terminal. You get this path after your denon installation is complete.

```
export PATH="/Users/<your account>/.deno/bin:$PATH"
```

Now try running your denon cmds.

Answer (score 3):

After installation, just run "export" commands shown in terminal:

> Deno was installed successfully to /Users/John/.deno/bin/deno
>
> Manually add the directory to your $HOME/.zshrc (or similar)

```
export DENO_INSTALL="/Users/John/.deno"
export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the reason why denon is a command not found is that the deno bin pathname is not declared in the system PATH.

You can see that yourself by running the command:

```
echo $PATH
```

You have to add the deno binary path to your system PATH.

The instructions are available to you when you install denon, e.g. here's the output after denon install:

```
✅ Successfully installed denon
/Users/<YOUR-USERNAME>/.deno/bin/denon
ℹ️  Add /Users/<YOUR-USERNAME>/.deno/bin to PATH
    export PATH="/Users/<YOUR-USERNAME>/.deno/bin:$PATH"
```

Edit your shell profile file, e.g. .profile, .bashrc, .zshrc, etc and include the deno bin path.

If you don't know which shell you have for the matter, run:

```
echo $SHELL
```

For my case, that'll be `/bin/zsh` and I have a `.zshrc` file, where I add or edit as follows:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.deno/bin:$PATH"
```

To complete, you have to restart the terminal emulator or source the shell profile file, e.g. for my case I'd:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Confirm everything is working by:

```
denon --version
```

You'd get

```
[*] [main] vX.X.X
```

That's all!